# Filtering in MongoDB with own fields

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm trying to filter mongodb documents by its own fields, specifically, time, ie:

```
{time1: timeval1, time2: timeval2}
```

I want to be able to get a result set (like with .find()) where timeval1 is greater than timeval2.

I don't know how to do this with $gt and couldn't find anything similar. Any ideas on how to do this?

I'm accessing it from pymongo inside a djangi project... but all I want is the mongodb query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$where` operator, and a javascript expression to write your query logic.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D

```
> db.newColl.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fbdcdd6e79d66d9e681b185"), "time1" : 123, "time2" : 22 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fbdcddee79d66d9e681b186"), "time1" : 11, "time2" : 220 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fbdcde6e79d66d9e681b187"), "time1" : 331, "time2" : 2120 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fbdcdece79d66d9e681b188"), "time1" : 1, "time2" : 20 }

> db.newColl.find({'$where' : 'this.time1 > this.time2' });

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fbdcdd6e79d66d9e681b185"), "time1" : 123, "time2" : 22 }


> db.newColl.find({'$where' : 'this.time1 < this.time2' });

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fbdcddee79d66d9e681b186"), "time1" : 11, "time2" : 220 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fbdcde6e79d66d9e681b187"), "time1" : 331, "time2" : 2120 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fbdcdece79d66d9e681b188"), "time1" : 1, "time2" : 20 }
```

> 

Comment: When using $where, it is good to be aware that its performance is much worse than "normal" queries. From mongodb manual: "Use $where only when you must it is significantly slower." Related advice is to try to filter the result set with normal query expressions as far as possible before the $where in order to cut down the number of documents processed by $where.